# jQuery: Something is delaying animations

Tags: javascript, jquery

What makes the animation delay?
All jQuery on the site is having some sort of delay..

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
       var elementTop = $('body').offset().top; 
       var position = elementTop+ $(window).scrollTop();
       if(position >= 20){
           $('#top').animate({top: '40px'}, 300);
       } else if(position < 20){
           $('#top').animate({top: '80px'}, 300);
       }
console.log(position);
  });   
});
```

Live:
[Link here](http://tipsafilm.se/flatfilthy1/index.html) - It's the menu/navigation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is being fired each time you scroll. The `animate` methods are being concatenated, running one after the other. To achieve what you want, you need to stop the current animation and start a new one:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var elementTop = $('body').offset().top,
        position = elementTop+ $(window).scrollTop();

        if (position >= 20){
            $('#top').stop().animate({top: '40px'}, 300);
        }
        else if (position < 20) {
           $('#top').stop().animate({top: '80px'}, 300);
        }
    });   
});
```